# ng-Repeat don't repeat on start

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, swiper.js

i'm very new in programming, and of course in AngularJS, but i'll try make my question simple.

I have a Angularjs seed, and one of my partial is using a swiper . I'm trying to use a ng-repeat to fill all of my pricing tables, but on start it only show one.

Now the strange part, if i hit F12 to open the console, it show all of my pricing table's filled with the information correctly.

Here is the code:

```
            <div class="row">
            <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide" ng-repeat="list in mercados">
                <fieldset>
                    <ul class="pricing-table">
                    <li class="title" id="titulo"> {{list.me_nome}} </li>
                    <li class="lotacao" id="lotacao"> {{list.me_lotacao}} </li>
                    <li class="description" id="morada"><h5> {{list.me_morada}} </h5></li>
                    <li class="description" id="horario"><h6>Horário: <li> {{list.me_horario}} <li> {{list.me_horariofds}} </li></li></h6></li>
                    <li class="cta-button"><a class="medium button round" href="#dashespacos" data-reveal-id="frmEmissaoFat">Entrar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pagination"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When i open the console and hit F5, the console show me this: 
`[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]` 
(and only 1 pricing table is show).

When i close the console and hit F12 again, the console show me this:

```
Array[10]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
length: 10
__proto__: Array[0]
```

And it show all my princing tables.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works:

```
<div class="swiper-slide" ng-repeat="list in mercados">
    <fieldset ng-repeat="(key,value) in list">
        <div>{{value}}</div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

For styling the contents conditionally, you can use **ng-class**.

Comment: I think this is what you are asking:

`[{"me_id":"1","me_nome":"Mercado de Oeiras","me_morada":"Largo 5 de Outubro","me_horario":"Seg. a Sexta – 7h às 14h","me_lotacao":"Não há lugares disponíveis","me_horariofds":"Sábado - 7h às 14h"},{"me_id":"2","me_nome":...] `